# Simplifying an sf object to remove overlapping linestrings

Tags: r, gis, r-sf

I have a sf object which represents multiple bus routes in a city. I would like to simplify this sf object to remove the overlapping routes. The end result should be a sf object with a single line for each road where there is one (or more) bus routes.

I want to go from this...
[image: lines]

to this...
[image: simpler_lines]

I've tried various functions from the sf package and igraph. Using the underlying road network may facilitate finding a solution.

Here's the sample data that I would like to simplify:

```
library(sf)
lines <- st_sfc(list(st_linestring(rbind( c(0,0), c(5, 5), c(10,10) )), 
                     st_linestring(rbind( c(0, 0), c(4, 5), c(10,9) )), 
                     st_linestring(rbind( c(10,0), c(4,5), c(10,10) )),
                     st_linestring(rbind( c(0,10), c(5, 10), c(10,9) )),
                     st_linestring(rbind( c(0,9), c(5, 9), c(10,10) ))
                     ))

road_network <- st_sfc(list(st_linestring(rbind( c(0, 0), c(2,3), c(4, 5), c(8,7), c(10,10) )), 
                            st_linestring(rbind( c(10,0), c(7,2), c(4,5) )),
                            st_linestring(rbind( c(10,10), c(9,6), c(8, 5), c(10,0) )),
                            st_linestring(rbind( c(0,10), c(2,9), c(5, 10), c(8,9), c(10,10) ))))
```

Comment: One potential way would be to choose some tolerance and "snap to grid" all the intersections. The downside of this is that the grid you choose may not be perfectly aligned to the real-world road. See this answer using the `lwgeom` package: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/317209/142423

Comment: 1) Are you able to identify which individual line segments (n=9) are 'correct'? If not, the only way to achieve your goal is to snap your data to a 'real world' road network. 2) This is assuming you want your bus routes to align to an existing road network? 3) If so, do you have an associated road network dataset? 4) Do the bus routes have any other associated variables such as the road and direction they travel along?

Comment: Thanks @LTyrone - I've added an example road network.

Comment: Thanks for highlighting the lwgeom package @Brian

Comment: If you have the road network, you can use `sf::st_snap` instead of an arbitrary grid to snap to. Might need to fiddle with the tolerance settings.

Comment: As Brian stated, `sf::st_snap()` will get you a result. However, it is not without issues. For instance, if you have a major road represented by two lines, one for each direction, it is highly likely you'll get erroneous snapping behaviour e.g. a northbound bus route may snap back and forth between the north and southbound lanes. Ways to avoid this is to use bus stops if available, ensure lines and their nodes are 'directional' relative to your bus routes (the road network should already have this), or use a combination of the two. More often than not bus stop gps data are freely available.

Comment: If you can access the bus stop data, you'll be able to avoid a lot of headaches by using those as a basis to generate your bus routes. Either way, if you respond to these comments with an update, I'll see what I can do.

Comment: Where does the bus route data come from, is it GTFS?

Comment: Thanks everyone for your comments and input. I think I might have confused the problem by trying to provide simple reproducible example data. @SymbolixAU, LTyrone in my actual case I have GTFS data including stops and a road network that I could snap to as Brian suggests. My end goal is to create a bus network layer without overlapping lines or lines stacked on top of each other. My apologies for the confusion.

Comment: does your GTFS come with a `shapes` layer?